# Can I create model in Django without automatic ID?

Tags: python, django, orm, model

I need a table without a primary key (in Django it was created automatically). So my question is: **Can I create a model without an ID/primary key?**

I'm using Django 1.7.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You *can* create a model without an auto-incrementing key, but you *cannot* create one without a primary key.

From the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields):

> If Django sees you’ve explicitly set [`Field.primary_key`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.primary_key), it won’t add the automatic id column.
>
> Each model requires exactly one field to have `primary_key=True` (either explicitly declared or automatically added).

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't. Excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields):

> Each model requires exactly one field to have primary_key=True (either explicitly declared or automatically added).

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution.

Since django need Primary Key (either it's composite or single-field ID) so, I've tried to set primary_key=True in every fields in its composite-key combination, and add those fields in Meta and groups in unique_together

```python
class ReportPvUv(models.Model):
    report_id = models.ForeignKey(Reports, primary_key=True)
    rdate = models.DateField(primary_key=True)
    fdate = models.DateTimeField(primary_key=True)
    ga_pv = models.BigIntegerField()
    ga_uv = models.BigIntegerField()
    ur_pv = models.BigIntegerField()
    ur_uv = models.BigIntegerField()
    da_pv = models.BigIntegerField()
    da_uv = models.BigIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'report_pv_uv'
        unique_together = ('report_id', 'rdate', 'fdate')
```

and when I run makemigrations, there are no ID field in it's migrations script :D

thanks everybody

Comment: Oh no !!. You cannot set multiple primary keys. You need to set it as `unique=True` and have only one primary key

Comment: Multiple column primary keys are **not** supported by Django. There are many issues with this approach. See https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys

Comment: actually this is what i needed coz i have to deal with wrongly designed db

Comment: Facing composite key in legacy database I can't imagine why Django ORM doesn't support this as ticket has been raised about 12 years ago. It would be nice feature.