# Django Admin cannot render tables without Primary Key

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

I implemented Django Admin in my web for administering all tables in my models. It´s working correctly until I try to see (for editing, adding, deleting records) a random table without primary key. If I try to access to this table the message **unknown column xxx.id in field list** appears.

I know Django is adding id field to tables without primary key. 
What could work for me? I dont mind if I have to show id field in list_field but if I try Django warning me this field doesnt exist. 
Could I define a unique value for solve this (my tables which doesnt have PK, has unique together instead...)

I tried to add a primary key property to a random field in the model´s class with those issues. That is working but I need to not have restrictions over fields and if I add this PK I cant repeat this value in others records.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've made changes to the model in question, you might need to migrate. In your project's root directory (or wherever the `manage.py` file is) type

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
```

Then type

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

It could be that you added a model field to the model, but it's not in the database yet, so you get this error when you try to edit it in admin.

**UPDATE**

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516086/can-i-create-model-in-django-without-automatic-id) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253817/mysql-gives-an-unknown-column-user-id-in-field-list-error-using-djangos-a), it sounds like Django tried to auto-add an `id` column since you didn't define a primary key on your model. That `id` may not have propagated to the database. Therefore try

```
$ python manage.py dbshell
```

Now you can add the column straight to the database table

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE your_table_name ADD id integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
mysql> exit;
```

Then try reloading your admin page...

Comment: Nope, I did it and the problem is still happening. Could be something related with the foreign keys and dont have primary key? If I added a random primary key in a radom field the problem is solved....

Comment: Thanks again Ryan... It works... I just remember, hibernate and entity forces you the same. You should have a primary key if you want to map tables into classes. Great!!